# mongodb Temporary Collection or Aggregate on find result

Tags: mongodb

I have to generate a dynamic report.

I have a complex query which returns result using db.collection.find() and has millions of records in it.

Now I want to perform aggregate operation on this result.

I tried inserting into a collection and than executing aggregate function on it using below:

```
db.users.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { db.usersDummy.insert(myDoc); } );
```

But this does not seems to be feasible to temporarily insert data and then perform aggregate operation on it.

Is there any way mongoDB supports Temporary tables or perform aggregate operation directly on find result?

Comment: You would typically just include your complex `find` query in an initial `$match` stage of your `aggregate` pipeline.  Did you try that?

Comment: Thanks Johnny i tried the suggestion given and it is working. I am new to mongoDB and was not aware of it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by  JohnnyHK i am using `$match` in aggregation to run the huge collection instead of creating a dummy collection

So closing this question